# My mac has 64-bit EFI, but it only boots with 32-bit kernel

Tags: startup, kernel, 64-bit

I followed the guide at
http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html
to boot into 64-bit mode. I had no problems with the instructions and on the boot screen it says "PAE enabled, 64bit mode enabled" but when the system boots, both **uname -a** and **System Profiler** tell me that it has booted into 32-bit mode.

I really need to boot into the 64-bit kernel, what should I do?

System is MacBook Unibody (Early 2009, 6 GB RAM, 2.4 Intel CPU, 10.6.6)

Comment: Why do you "need" to boot into the 64-bit kernel? It's not necessary for anything...

Comment: There are several methods listed on that page. Did you try all of them? Same results for all? Please refine question with more details. Don't just link to that page, tell us what you did.

Comment: @mankoff: I tried all and all combinations, no results. I did them all.

Comment: @itaiferber: I explicitly told that I need to do so, hence your comment was flagged as bugous. I have libs that link against 64bit kernel modules.

Comment: What is the output of `ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi`?

Comment: | |   "firmware-abi" = <"EFI64">
As I said all requirements described in that doc are met.

Comment: @AbiusX I'm sorry for that. Most people incorrectly assume they "need" to boot into a 64-bit kernel to run 64-bit apps and I was trying to assess the situation. You did the right thing though.

Comment: @itaiferber: no problems, but any solutions? :D

Comment: Note that the message "PAE enabled, 64bit mode enabled" does not mean the 64-bit kernel was used. But I guess that's obvious to you now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

64-bit Mac CPUs cannot boot 64-bit kernel due to one of the following reasons:

1. The machine has 32-bit EFI.
2. The machine’s model is prohibited from booting K64 through a hardcoded list
   within the boot loader. (The list excludes "non-Pro" machines.)

Both limitations are artificial and imposed by Apple, although the first one is important because if a 32-bit EFI were allowed to boot the kernel wouldn't be able to use firmware services.

IF you really, really, really want to boot these machines with a 64-bit kernel, you'll need to perform hackery on `/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi`. This is quite risky. More info:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200602233051/http://osxbook.com/blog/2009/08/31/is-your-machine-good-enough-for-snow-leopard-k64/)

Comment: But my EFI is 64 bit, And 64 bit is enabled on boot (as it says) But only when I boot it sais 64bit not loaded.

Comment: Because your machine is not PRO, you cannot do it unless you try to modify the efi (as described by ghoppe in his link). There's a list that **excludes** your machine, no matter how 64 bits EFI you have.

Comment: Unfortunately the boot.efi defined in that article is too old and its hash is not the same as mine, So the byte refered to not found. Any more recent instructions?

Answer (score 3):

64-bit kernel mode is not supported on any of the MacBooks (see [Apple's KB article #HT3770](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770)), even if they have a 64-bit CPU and 64-bit EFI firmware.  I don't know why it's not possible to boot them 64-bit, but I haven't found a way to do it (I'm in the same boat, as I have a 2007 MacBook Pro, also 64-bit EFI, but Apple only supports 64-bit kernel on the MacBook Pros introduced in 2008 or later).

Comment: But mine is 2009?

Comment: @AbiusX: According the Apple KB article, MacBook **Pros** since 2008 can boot K64; none of the non-Pro MacBooks can.  Sorry.

Comment: Well a month after i bought this, this was changed to pro. Nothing changed but only the name.

Comment: @AbiusX You really don't know if "only the name" changed, maybe some other internal, in either case, the answer is simple, you cannot boot into 64 bits with a "non pro" Macbook, unless you try the boot.efi modification (which is risky) but might work.

Comment: @Martin: I think modification of boot.efi wont be so risky, i can simply time machine back to my old system if anything goes wrong, right? Would u please provide me with modification instructions?

Comment: @AbiusX: The link ghoppe posted has instructions for modifying boot.efi.

Comment: @AbiusX: Check the link given by ghoppe, near the end you have to change a bit in the hex file. Handle with care ;) Rather than a Time Machine I'd suggest you create a bootable CLONE of your drive. A lot of things can go wrong forcing you to reinstall the OS. You're not touching a config, you're touching booting files. If you mess up your OS X won't boot anymore. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plist at /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist which controls which kernel gets used at boot time.

You can hold 6 & 4 to boot into 64-bit kernel mode while booting. Also, you can boot 32-bit by holding 3 & 2 while booting. Or you can try

```
sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture x86_64
```

and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same computer as you.

There is no way to boot in 64 bit mode.

I tried modifying so many system files. It cannot be done, and it does not need to be.

Comment: If you haven't found a way, Do you think it means that there are non?

Comment: Given the amount of searching I did, yes.

Answer (score 0):

MacBooks like yours are artificially prohibited by Apple from booting the 64 bit kernel.  This restriction is in the boot.efi.  To bypass this restriction in the current 10.10.3 boot.efi you must do the following.

1) Create a copy of the boot.efi file and name it boot64.efi (boot.efi is usually located in /System/Library/CoreServices/   or on your esp partition

2) Using a hex editor search for the string 20 00 40 02 and replace it with 40 00 80 04

3) Save the boot64.efi file

4) bless the boot64.efi

5) sudo nvram boot-args="arch=x86_64"

6) reboot