# Why isn't my MacBook running 64 bit mode?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My mac has 64-bit EFI, but it only boots with 32-bit kernel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/my-mac-has-64-bit-efi-but-it-only-boots-with-32-bit-kernel)

Why isn't my MacBook running 64 bit mode? It's a mid-2010 model, "MacBook 7,1" , with a Core-2 Duo. why would it run in 32-bit mode? Could it be because I've only got 2GB of RAM?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these machines booted into 64bit. (the new macbook pros do).

You can hold down 6 and 4 whilst rebooting for a temporary 64bit boot (if available)

If that works, you can try this in terminal and then reboot

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot 'Kernel Flags' 'arch=x86_64'
```

This will make the mac boot in 64bit mode by default.

Comment: Are there any negative side effects to booting into 64-bit mode?

Comment: The 64-bit versions of apps take slightly more RAM because they need to hold 64-bit addresses instead of 32-bit. This is only a very minor difference. I can't think of anything else though.

Comment: like your tip of holding down 6 and 4 key at bootup

Comment: I don't think this will work for non-Pro MacBooks.

Comment: Ah yes. Misread that it wasn't a pro.